# Get WooCommerce product details and transfer them to a custom DB table

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, mysql

I'm currently doing a registering service for products with WordPress and WooCommerce.

All products that customers can register will be in the WooCommerce database, but not visible on frontend.

Here is my goal: make a form with a dropdown list (items inside it will be all my WooCommerce products), where user can pick his product. He will then write when he bought his product, name, address, etc.

The path will be : get all information I want from product the database of WooCommerce before using it later -> get personal info written inside form on frontend -> write all that data inside a table in MySQL.

I tried with `wc_get_products();` but I do not know how to get specific information (name, URL of photo, SKU, and some specific information like warranty period), it returns some weird array.

I already mapped my table for MySQL. I just need to know how to get info and write to it.

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

With `wc_get_products()` you will get an array of `WC_Product` Objects.

**Get product properties**

Each `WC_Product` Object is a CRUD object with protected data. That data is accessible using related [`WC_Product`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html) and [`WC_Data`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Data.html) methods.

For custom meta data `(or custom fields)`, you will use the `WC_Data` `get_meta()` method on your specific `meta_keys` that you can find in `wp_postmeta` database table for a product ID *(`post_id`)*. So for example if the custom `meta_key` is **`_my_image_url`** you will get the value from the `WC_Product` Object using:

```
$value = $product->get_meta('_my_image_url');
```

Below is a more complete example, using everything:

```
// The WC_Product_Query
$products = wc_get_products('limit' => 10);

// Loop though `WC_Product` Objects
foreach ( $products as $product ) {
    $product_id      = $product->get_id(); // The product ID
    $product_name    = $product->get_name(); // The product name
    $product_sku     = $product->get_sku(); // The product SKU
    $product_price   = $product->get_price(); // The product price
    $image_url       = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $product->get_image_id() ); // The product image URL

    ## ----- Custom meta data ----- ##

    $custom_value    = $product->get_meta('_custom_key'); // Custsom meta data
}
```

You can also use [`get_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) WordPress function **from the product Id** *(or the post ID)* like:

```
$product_name    = get_the_title($product_id); // The product name
$product_sku     = get_post_meta($product_id, '_sku', true); // The product SKU
$product_price   = get_post_meta($product_id, '_price', true); // The product price
$image_url       = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_meta($product_id, '_thumbnail_id', true) ); // The product image URL

## ----- Custom meta data ----- ##

$custom_value    = get_post_meta($product_id, '_custom_key', true); // Custsom meta
```

**Updating product properties**

Now you can also use [any available setter method](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html) to change product properties values and you will use at the end `save();` method to save data and refresh cached data.

**Transfer to a custom DB table**

To transfer some data in a custom table, you will use [`WPDB`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) WordPress class that allow you to make any SQL query to WordPress custom tables.